# Jquery script is acting weird on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the Jquery script below to make sure the first div's height of my page is equal to the viewport of the user's screen.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).resize(function() {
      $(".introduction").css("height", window.innerHeight+"px");
    });
</script>
</body>
```

where .introduction is the class of my first div. It work well on my tablet, but is acting wierd when seen on my big desktop screen. It only works if I right-click => inspect the page and then close it up.

any ideas ?

Here is the page I'm working on at the moment:

http://shotokanlaprairie.com/notre-dojo/

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to put the script inside a `document.ready` and then trigger the event as such to fire it at launch

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  /* your logic */
}).trigger("resize");
```

Comment: I dont understand how but it is working now only by adding ".trigger("resize")". Thank you !